# WP, pass several id's to query

Tags: php, wordpress

```
function my_relationship_query( $args, $field, $post_id ) {

// only show children of the current post being edited
$args['post_parent'] = $post_id;


// return
return $args;
```

}

How  for example I could pass two parameters as post_id ? Is the only way of doing that includes writing some meta queries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass an array of post IDs to `post_parent__in`, per [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) (assuming `$args` is representative of WP_Query params):

```
$post_id_array = array( $id1, $id2 );

function my_relationship_query( $args, $field, $post_id_array ) {

    // only show children of the current post being edited
    $args['post_parent__in'] = $post_id_array;

    // return
    return $args;
}
```